# Equivalence class for the following relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

A relation of $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as $a\sim b : a^4-b^2=b^4-a^2$

Show that $\sim$ is equivalence relation (I have done this part)

Determine the equivalence class $[-1]_\sim$

Prove or disprove: Every equivalence class in $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ contains exactly 2 real numbers.

I am facing difficulty in second and third part of the question.

For the second one I think it is $[-1]_\sim=\{-1,1\}$ as $-1\sim x: (-1)^4-x^2 =x^4-(-1)^2 $ so both $-1$ and $1$ are proving the equality.

I think the third statement is true but how can I prove it?
Please help.

Comment: *Hint:* Rearranged, $a^4+a^2 = b^4+b^2$ or rather $a^2(a^2+1)=b^2(b^2+1)$.  Now... recognize that $x^2=(-x)^2$ for all real $x$

Comment: As for your attempt on the second., I hope that is a typo.  It should be clear that $(-1)$ is not related to $0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz so for the second one it is $-1$ and $+1$ ?

Comment: Yes, and the punchline is that $[x]_\sim = \{x,-x\}$ for all $x$, noting that $0=-0$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think for $0$ we have only one which is $0$ it self or can we use $0=-0$ as you said in your comment?

Comment: However you prefer to write it, the equivalence class of zero has one element which is true regardless whether you wrote it as $[0]_\sim = \{0\}$ or if you wrote it as $[0]_\sim = \{0,-0\}$ since $\{0,-0\}$ is a one element set just like how $\{5,5\}$ is a one element set.  For sets, we don't care about redundancy, we only count each element one time even if it appeared more than once.  In describing the final result, I preferred the latter so that I could describe the result for *all* $x$ in one phrase rather than having to break into cases.

Comment: @JMoravitz okay thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange: $a^4 - b^4 = b^2 - a^2$
But $a^4 - b^4 = (a^2 - b^2)(a^2 + b^2)$ (DOTS)
So $(a^2 - b^2)(a^2 + b^2) = b^2 - a^2$

(1) Assume $a^2 - b^2 \neq 0$
Then divide both sides by $a^2 - b^2$
$a^2 + b^2 = -1$
Since $a^2$ and $b^2$ are both positive in $\Bbb R$, this is a contradiction.

(2) Therefore $a^2 - b^2 = 0$, or $a^2 = b^2$.
Therefore $b = \pm a$ and each equivalence class of a comprises $\{a, -a \}$.
The equivalence class of $-1$ is $\{-1, 1 \}$.

Comment: JMoravitz.  Of course, I missed the 0.  Not true for all elements of R!

Comment: but cant we say $0=-0$

Comment: Please do learn (it's quick) how to type MathJax in this site to decently  write mathematics...That would enhance greatly the appearnce of your answers.

Comment: "but cant we say 0=−0"  Of course.  And that is *exactly* why $[0]_\sim = \{0,-1\}=\{0\}$ has exactly one and not two elements.  If a number can be written two different ways, it is still only one number, and not two.

Answer (score 1):

Follow definitions.

$[-1] = \{b\in \mathbb R|(-1)^2 - b^2=b^4 -(-1)^2\}=$

$\{b\in \mathbb R| 1-b^2 = b^4 -1\}=$

$\{b\in \mathbb R| b^4+b^2-2 = 0\}=$

$\{b\in \mathbb R| (b^2+2)(b-1)(b+1)=0\}=$

$\{b\in \mathbb R| b^2 = -2\lor b=1\lor b=-1\}=$

$\{1,-1\}$

As for the second:

$[a] = \{b\in \mathbb R| a^4-b^2 = b^4 -a^2\}=$

$\{b \in \mathbb R|b^4+b^2 -(a^4+a^2) = 0\}$

Now potentially $b^4 + b^2-(a^4 + a^2)=0$ may have up to four solutions.

Indeed in the case of $[-1]$ we found $b \in [-1]$ if $(b^2 + 2)(b+1)(b-1)=0$ had two elements because $b^2 + 2=0$ is impossible.

We can use quadratic formula to solve $b^4 + b^2 -(a^4+a^2)$ for $b$ but it's probably easier to factor:

$b^4 + b^2-(a^4 + a^2)=0$

$(b^4 -a^4) + (b^2 - a^2) = 0$

$(b^2 +a^2)(b^2 - a^2)+(b^2 -a^2) =0$

$(b^2 + a^2 + 1)(b^2-a^2)=0$

$(b^2  +a^2 + 1)(b-a)(b+a)=0$.

Well, $b^2 + a^2 + 1 > 0$ so the only solutions are $b=\pm a$ and that will always be the case that $[a] = \{a,-a\}$ so.....

but what if $a = 0$.  Then $[0] = \{0,-0\} =\{0\}$ has only one element.

And we can show that directly $0^4 -b^2 = b^4 - 0^2$

$b^4 + b^2 = 0$ so $b^2(b^2 + 1)=0$ so $b^2 = 0$ or $b^2 =-1$ so $b = 0$.

So the third is false but *only* because $[0]$ has one element. For all others it is true.

Not  $\sim$ is *exactly* the same as the relationship $a = \pm b$.

Note:  $a^4 -b^2 = b^4 - a^2 \iff a =\pm b$

In hindsight had we proven that from the *very* beginning we wouldn't have need to do so much work.

Live and learn.